# How to show margin of block in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, margin

I use notepad++ or extension for Visual Studio and I have seen the line (margin) of the block like the below image.
[image]

Can Eclipse do this? Thanks!

Answer (score -2):

You can turn on the "Show whitespace characters" option under General -> Editors -> Text Editors.  I find that too distracting.

Eclipse has a different way to control the display of blocks of code.

[image: PhotoView constructor open]

See the circle with a dash right after the line number 65.  You can left click on that circle to close the block.

[image: PhotoView constructor closed]

You can hover your cursor over the circle with the plus sign to see the "hidden" code.

Left clicking on the circle will open the control block again.

Comment: Yeah, it's amazing. However, I mean if Eclipse has alignment block (like above image I posted), I can see anything more clearly.